# Can some SQL queries be executed while the others fail?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have read from some posts that it is a better practice to execute queries one by one instead of doing the multi-query function in PHP files. I wonder say I have two `mysqli_query` functions, is it possible that the first query succeeds and MySQL Database has been changed accordingly when the next query fails?

If this is the case, I need to execute the second query only if the first succeeded, for example ( create table, then insert data to that table). Is putting an if statement for the condition that the first query is successful the best way of ensuring this?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. I would probably use a transaction for that particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. If your database engine supports [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) (e.g. InnoDB) then you can use transactions. They enable you to stash changes until you call commit manually. This has nothing to do with multi-query.

You can use transactions in PDO as well as in mysqli. Although as always you should choose PDO whenever possible.

Here is an example of a simple transaction using mysqli. The whole thing is wrapped in a try-catch so that if one of these queries fails then the other ones are rolled back.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// start transaction
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
try {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE(?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO hobby(uid, name) VALUE(?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $hobby);
    $stmt->execute();

    // save changes
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

In the example above, either both queries are successful or neither of them.

Create table cannot be used with transactions, however, because it is a DDL statement and they always cause an implicit commit when they are executed.

Comment: It is important to note that transactions don't work with the myisam engine -- only engines with transaction support like innodb will work with code like this.  So all the tables involved in a transaction must be InnoDB engine tables.

Comment: hi Dharman, does the sql query finished execution right after the query function is executed? for example, in your code does the query finish right after this line of code? $stmt->execute();

Comment: @AndyLin The query is executed on the MySQL server when you call `execute()` but if you use transactions then changed are not persisted until you call `commit()`

Comment: @Dharman yes, without the transaction is what I meant, so on the MySQL, after the execute() function is called, queries will be applied. Thank you.